# pg_catalog does not exist in AWS RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pgadmin

I am trying to view pg_catalog.pg_stat_activity in pgAdmin 4, but I cannot seem to find where it is (if it exists) on my RDS PostgreSQL DB. Where should it be?

There is no pg_catalog schema, and I have made sure that the correct parameters are turned on in the individual DB instances (e.g. track_counts, track_activities). These DBs are part of a cluster that does not have these parameters turned on, but from what I read online, that shouldn't matter. Am I looking in the right place, or is something turned off still?

Comment: What is the SQL statement and the error message?

Comment: For example, SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity returns data, but I do not see it in the user friendly view on the left side pane of pgAdmin. I want to know how many tables like pg_stat_activity I have.

Comment: Then Amazon has removed permissions from some catalog tables, which will break most client tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, pgAdmin doesn't show those tables in the GUI due to it being AWS, however, I was able to query them (e.g. pg_stat_activity) through the query tools.